# PDO/PHP Rating System, How to Review a Specific Target ID

Tags: php, rating, review

Sorry about the title don't really know what to say

I have two tables on my database, a reviews table which is for the reviews/ratings, and a recipes table which just contains a bunch of recipes I want the user to review.

Right now if I rate one of the recipes so if I give it a 1/10, all the recipes will receive this review which I do not want, I want one recipe to have the target review and the others unaffected, I tried to make recipe_id a foreign id to the recipe table but nothing happened, I'm not entirely sure what to do here, I will provide images of the two tables but here is the code,

```
[<div class="review-form-container mt-3">
      <?php
      $rating = (int) $_POST\["review_rating"\];
      $recipeid = (int) $_POST\["recipe_id"\];

      if($rating){
        $query = "INSERT INTO reviews (recipe_id, review_score) VALUES (:recipe_id, :review_score)";
        $result = $DBH->prepare($query);
        $result->bindParam(':recipe_id', $recipeid);
        $result->bindParam(':review_score', $rating);
        if($result->execute()){
          echo "<strong class=”mb-3”>Your review has been added!</strong>";
        }
      }
      ?>

      <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="#">
        <div class="form-group mr-2">
          <select name="review_rating" class="form-control">
            <option value="1">1 Star</option>
            <option value="2">2 Star</option>
            <option value="3">3 Star</option>
            <option value="4">4 Star</option>
            <option value="5">5 Star</option>
            <option value="6">6 Star</option>
            <option value="7">7 Star</option>
            <option value="8">8 Star</option>
            <option value="9">9 Star</option>
            <option value="10">10 Star</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="addreview">Add Review</button>
      </form>]
```

[Review Table with some reviews that do not work yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4nRT.png)

[Recipe Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wM46.png)

Comment: There is no `recipe_id` in your form so the review will not be linked to a specific recipe.

Comment: Sorry, new to this, how do you propose I insert it?